# Opengl textures change color of everything

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl

Whenever I render textures, all shapes get the color of the texture. I'm not sure why, but I think it's something to do with the way I render textures. Here's what I use to draw textures:

```
public void drawTex(Texture t, int x, int y, int width, int height)
    {
        t.bind();
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0,0);
        glVertex2f(x,y);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0);
        glVertex2f(x+t.getTextureWidth(),y);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1);
        glVertex2f(x+t.getTextureWidth(),y+t.getTextureHeight());
        glTexCoord2f(0,1);
        glVertex2f(x,y+t.getTextureHeight());
        glEnd();
    }
```

Now I draw shapes like this:

```
public void drawQuad(int x, int y, int width, int height, float r, float g, float b)
    {

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    //  glColor3f (r, g, b);
        glVertex2f(x, y);
        glVertex2f(x + width, y);
        glVertex2f(x + width, y + height);
        glVertex2f(x, y + height);
        glEnd();
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unbind your texture object after using it for drawing certain shape.

```
// In Texture class add
void unbind()
{
 glBindTexture(0);
}

public void drawTex(Texture t, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
        t.bind();
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(0,0);
        glVertex2f(x,y);
        glTexCoord2f(1,0);
        glVertex2f(x+t.getTextureWidth(),y);
        glTexCoord2f(1,1);
        glVertex2f(x+t.getTextureWidth(),y+t.getTextureHeight());
        glTexCoord2f(0,1);
        glVertex2f(x,y+t.getTextureHeight());
        glEnd();
        t.unbind();
}
```

Though, this raise the question of [how leaky OpenGL states could be used with OOP languages](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Common_Mistakes#The_Object_Oriented_Language_Problem). Is it appropriate to call OpenGL functions that can affect the global state in class objects.. One way to handle this is to restrict OpenGL calls in certain(one?) places, for example `OpenGLRenderer` class.

Comment: Thanks, i never saw any tutorials unbind it so I thought it was my error.